# 0xc000021a Windows Error

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, bsod

I installed Windows 8.1 from Windows 7 a few weeks ago, and have since had to reinstall THREE times because of this same error.

Basically, after a few days of normal use, I start getting "Shockwave Flash Player has stopped working" in google chrome, firefox, windows apps, etc.

So, I go ahead and try to restart windows. Shuts down just fine. But, it wont start. I now get the automatic repair, which doesn't work. Error code i'm given from the BSOD: 0xc000021a. Safe Mode does not work.

Some programs i've had installed: Chrome, Photoshop, Firefox, Trello (Windows App), Java, SublimeText 2, FileZilla, Skype, and a few others that don't come to mind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In the mean time, I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

There is more information on this topic located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on the Microsoft support site. After reading that, you may decide what you think is best. If you are installing from a disc, you may have a defect in the disc, which could cause a problem with the installation.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: "the most common culprits are third-party applications"